# File sharing on linux / unix

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-sharing

is there a built in file sharing for linux or unix systems, that is not Samba / Windows based, just for sharing files between 'nix systems?  And is sharing in this way supported by gnome and other desktop GUIs?  I'm using ubuntu.

Thanks,
craig

Answer (score 1):

You can also share files through SSH, which is secure.

Comment: True, sshfs works wonders. But data encryption has a slight impact on performance.

Comment: Not too bad for casual sharing, it all depends on the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on NFS exports. I don't think they're terribly secure (use Samba!) but they do the job.

Comment: NFS4 can be pretty secure when using the new connection encryption and authentication mechanisms.